# Grub; Usb keyboard works sometimes, not always

Tags: grub, usb-keyboard

If I wait for grub to startup and I do nothing, the usb keyboard will not work and the computer never boots into anything.

If I use the usb keyboard to enter into bios and then exit it, or if I just hit random keys(like the arrow keys) during startup before grub, then when grub does come up the usb keyboard works and I can boot into an OS.

Any idea if their is a way to fix this, or do I just have to live with it and hit keys during startup?

Biostar motherboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using an Apple keyboard. After switching to a Logitech one it works fine. The Apple keyboard would only show up as a hub if I wasn't pressing any keys. If I was pressing keys it would show up as a hub and keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have USB Keyboard support enabled on your BIOS settings.

Comment: I was using an Apple keyboard. After switching to a Logitech one it works fine. The Apple keyboard would only show up as a hub if I wasn't pressing any keys. If I was pressing keys it would show up as a hub and keyboard.